# PHP Using variables inside chdir()?

Tags: php, chdir

Using PHP,

chdir('../) works completely fine. However, when going the same path just having a declared variable instead, it prompts an error saying:

> Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

```
$var = "../";
chdir($var)
```

I have tried declaring $var with 's instead, and also tried to use " inside chdir but both cases gives same error.

why is this?

Comment: is chdir('../) a typo? I can't see a closing single quote, also is chdir($var) being used with no semi-colon? These issues could be causing side-effects if that's how they're typed up in your code.

Comment: Do you have any more code in your actual code in between those to lines? Is the above a real copy/paste or did you rewrite it here on SO? There shouldn't be any difference between hard coding the value and using a variable. I just tried it to be 100% sure.

Comment: Assuming there are no syntax errors in your actual code, there's no reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes i tried with chdir("$var"), did not work.

If i echo $var, it displays = " ../ "  without any spaces.
chdir($var) just doesnt work and the variable declaraton is right above it..

Comment: @PJohanson Please edit your question to include the full source code of your script. Also add a `var_dump($variablename)` statement before the `chdir()` line to output the variable of the `chdir()` call. And include the complete, unchanged error message you get from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late update, but the solution was to trim the variable in advance.

```
$query = '../';
chdir(trim($query));
```

When I posted this issue, I was not familiar with how to oppose the issue in a matter of clarity, but I still should've included that the variable input actually was originating from a textfield.

Thanks for all the support, however!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    $var = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "..";
    chdir($var);
```